# WAS 8.5 Network deployment automation/scripting

Tags: unix, websphere, jython, ibm-was, wsadmin

I'm using Websphere network deployment application server 8.5 on unix environment. I'm updating my existing applications on daily basis from admin console and i change the ***context root*** of each application depending upon the environment. I wanted to make this whole deployment process automated using only jythone/wsadmin/shell script. The script will accept the **path of the ear** which is going to reside on the unix server i.e. /export/opt/was85/temp and other various parameter like cluster name, server name and application name. Can anyone able to help me on this. thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Read out my on IBM on this. This may be exactly what you wanted with little modification in it.

https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/community/blogs/706a5f30-025f-4dc3-b162-01e918fe489e/entry/Application_Edition_Management_and_Automatic_Deployment_with_Ant_Script?lang=en

**EDIT**

You can find more options from this Link which are not covered in the script which I wrote.
https://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSAW57_8.5.5/com.ibm.websphere.base.doc/ae/rxml_taskoptions.html

Comment: Thanks Prerak, can it be possible to update the application. the above script install new application every time.

Comment: even if you update the application, it will follow the same process of Uninstalling it and and installing the updated version of it. See my edited Answer.

Answer (score 0):

This information is avaiable in the Infocenter for Websphere, where the jython examples are listed. Here is an example below with the context root update specified.

```
http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSAW57_8.5.5/com.ibm.websphere.nd.doc/ae/welcome_nd.html


AdminApplication.addUpdateSingleModuleFileToAnAppWithUpdateCommand         
(appName, fileContent, contentURI, contextRoot)
```

Example usage
[Windows]

```
AdminApplication.addUpdateSingleModuleFileToAnAppWithUpdateCommand      ("myApp","c:\DefaultWebApplication.war", "DefaultWebApplication.war", "/webapp/defaultapp")
```